# Write a user-defined WORKDAY function to return a Date from 2 Inputs (a Date, a Number)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to write a user-defined function to return JobPlnStartDate DATETIME with 2 inputs (EndDate, number)?

JobPlnStartDate = EndDate - number. Excluding Saturday, Sunday, and holidays.

Holidays can be taken from the [holidays] table: [holidays.date]

```
ALTER FUNCTION FN_ReturnWorkingDay
(
@EndDate DATETIME,
@Num int
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @n int = 0
DECLARE @JobPlnStartDate DATETIME = @EndDate - @n
WHILE (@n <= @Num)
    BEGIN
        IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @JobPlnStartDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
            BEGIN           
                SET @n = @n + 1 
                SET @JobPlnStartDate = @EndDate - @n            
            END;
    END;
RETURN @JobPlnStartDate
END
```

I tried to test with this line of code below but it seemed like an infinite loop:

```
SELECT dbo.FN_ReturnWorkingDay('2022-08-13 11:19:11.287', 12)
```

Could you please help me point out my mistake?

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what you're trying to accomplish? Also, what result would you expect from your test execution?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `date` instead of `datetime`?

Comment: Seriously consider a Calendar Table.   Then this becomes a simple query.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Out of curiosity, do sql-server has a special table named "Calendar Table"?

Comment: don't you want to increment @n outside of your if statement? otherwise when the if statement fails you get infinite loop

Comment: It is an infinite loop once your logic finds the weekend. And your logic does nothing with holidays. And if you're only interested in dates, then use that specific datatype.

Comment: @user14063792468  No.  This is something you have to build and customize.   There are many, many examples and sample builds

Comment: @user14063792468  Here is one for example  https://sqlskull.com/2020/05/21/generate-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Quick google tells me it is some table that belongs to sql-server users only. I'm a mere mortal, I will leave this technologies for more advanced SQL users.

Comment: @Marc Hi, I'm trying to write a function that is similar to the WORKDAY function in Excel. Here is the link: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-workday-function

Comment: @Dai a Date can't add or subtract with an integer in SQL server, but DateTime does.

Comment: @BryanDellinger I want to increment n if the if statement is True, otherwise, it should return the current value of n. The function should work similarly to the WORKDAY function in excel.  exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-workday-function

Comment: @SMor you're totally right. I didn't add the holidays logic yet because I wanted to solve this infinite loop first. How to fix the loop once the logic finds Saturday and Sunday? I tried to add an ELSE statement but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me and pointing out my mistakes in my code. I already figured out the solution for my code. This function works exactly like the WORKDAY function in Excel. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-workday-function

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_ReturnWorkingDay
(
   @EndDate DATETIME,
   @Num INT
 )
 RETURNS DATETIME
 AS
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @n INT 
   SET @n = 0
   DECLARE 
           @JobPlnStartDate DATETIME
          ,@IsSaturday INT
          ,@IsSunday INT
          ,@IsHoliday INT
   SET @JobPlnStartDate = @EndDate - @n
   WHILE (@n <= @Num)
          BEGIN                
                 SET @IsSaturday = CASE
                                     WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @JobPlnStartDate) = 'Saturday'
                                     THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                  END;

                 SET @IsSunday = CASE
                                     WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @JobPlnStartDate) = 'Sunday'
                                     THEN 1
                                     ELSE 0
                                  END;

                 SET @IsHoliday = CASE 
                                     WHEN CAST(@JobPlnStartDate AS DATE) IN (SELECT CAST(STARTDATE AS DATE) FROM CAL000_mst WHERE YEAR(STARTDATE) = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
                                     THEN 1 
                                     ELSE 0 
                                  END;


                 IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @JobPlnStartDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') 
                       BEGIN                
                              SET @JobPlnStartDate = @EndDate - @n - @IsHoliday                                        
                       END;
                 ELSE  
                       BEGIN 
                        SET @JobPlnStartDate = @EndDate - @n - @IsHoliday - @IsSaturday - @IsSunday                                
                       END;
                 SET @n = @n + 1      
                 SET @JobPlnStartDate = @JobPlnStartDate - @n
          END;
   RETURN @JobPlnStartDate + 1
 END
```